# WordPress plugin or theme for ads that can be closed by admin

Tags: wordpress

I have my website and I want to add a page for classified ads.

What I exactly need other than the obvious (register new user, log in pages, post ads for free, or for paid amount) is a theme or plugin that allows me to **manually close an ad and mark it as closed** and then the client can view their open ads, closed ones, and paid ones.